# Generalized linear model using quasi-likelihood

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, variance, quasi-likelihood

I am going to fit a model using quasi likelihood, (because the dispersion parameter `> 1`, `y` is a binary data). But when I using variance equals to `miu(1-miu), or miu^2*(1-miu)^2`, the Pearson residuals looks like this.

[image]

Do you have any idea why it looks like this, is there any specific variance I can use to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpreting residual diagnostic plots for glm models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29271/interpreting-residual-diagnostic-plots-for-glm-models)