# Logistic Regression vs ANOVA for categorical variables

Tags: regression, logistic, anova, categorical-data, diagnostic

In a problem that I have to predict a categorical variable (0/1) using a set of categorical variables, does it make any difference in **prediction accuracy** whether I use a logistic regression or ANOVA?

How about any differences in other areas such as:

1. Model Assumptions
2. Regression Diagnosis
3. Implementation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You want to predict a binary (0/1) variable, definitely start out with logistic regression. ANOVA is really a variant on usual linear regression (for continuous response), and uses some assumptions that are definite **not** true for binary response, like constant error variance.

As for the numbered points, this is a very broad question ... but note that logistic regression is a specific case of glm (generalized linear models), and usually methodology for glm's closely parallels that for ordinary linear regression. This is already widely discussed on this site, so I will just link to some relevant posts:

1. [Assumptions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logisti*+regress*+assumpt*+answers%3A1).
2. [Interpreting residual diagnostic plots for glm models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29271/interpreting-residual-diagnostic-plots-for-glm-models)