# Resolving heteroscedasticity in Poisson GLMM

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, heteroscedasticity, glmm

I have long-term collection data, and I'd like to test, whether the number of animals collected is influenced by weather effects. My model looks like below:

```
glmer(SumOfCatch ~ I(pc.act.1^2) +I(pc.act.2^2) + I(pc.may.1^2) + I(pc.may.2^2) + 
                   SampSize + as.factor(samp.prog) + (1|year/month), 
      control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9,npt=5)), 
      family="poisson", data=a2)
```

Explanation of the used variables:

- SumOfCatch: number of animals collected
- pc.act.1, pc.act.2: axes of a principal component representing weather conditions during sampling
- pc.may.1, pc.may.2: axes of a PC representing weather conditions in May
- SampSize: number of pitfall traps, or collecting transects of standard lengths
- samp.prog: method of sampling
- year: year of sampling (from 1993 to 2002)
- month: month of sampling (from Aug to Nov)

The fitted model's residuals show considerable inhomogeneity (heteroscedasticity?) when plotted against fitted values (see Fig.1):

[image: Residuals vs. Fitted values - Main model]

**My main question is: is this a problem making the reliability of my model questionable? If so, what can I do to resolve it?**

So far I have tried the followings:

- control for overdispersion by defining observation-level random effects, i.e. using a unique ID for each observation, and applying this ID variable as random effect; although my data do show considerable overdispersion, this did not help as the residuals became even more ugly (see Fig. 2)

[image: Residuals vs. Fitted values - Model with OD control]

- I fitted models without random effects, with quasi-Poisson glm and glm.nb; also yielded similar residual vs. fitted plots to the original model

As far as I know, there might be ways for the estimation of heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors, but I have failed to find any such method for Poisson (or any other kind of) GLMMs in R.

---

In response to @FlorianHartig: the number of observations in my dataset is N=554, I think this is a fair obs. number for such a model, but of course, the more the merrier. I post two figures, first of which is the DHARMa scaled residual plot (suggested by Florian) of the main model.

[image]

The second figure is from a second model, in which the only difference is that it contains the observation-level random effect (the first does not).

[image]

**UPDATE**

Figure of the relationship between a weather-variable (as predictor, i.e. x-axis) and sampling success (response):

[image: Weather-PC and sampling success]

**UPDATE II.**

Figures showing predictor values vs. residuals:

[image: Predictors vs. Residuals]

Comment: Have you considered running a nonparametric estimator? Or comparing an ols to a median regression? I realize that poisson is the dominant model in bio but GLMs are inconsistent under heteroscedasticity and OLS is not.

Comment: Sometimes overdispersion is caused by zero-inflation. In that case you could try a poisson model with zero-inflation parameter or a hurdle model. The glmmADMB package has great features to deal with this: http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/glmmADMB.html

Comment: Dear @Superpronker thanks for the suggestion, I did not checked OLS, I did not realize that this approach would be flexible enough to handle my data. I'll look into it

Comment: Dear @Niek in my data, there are no observations of zero - otherwise I did think of zeroinfl and hurdle models (in package 'pscl') due to their good handling of overdispersion, but they are only usable on data with zeros in the response. Back a few months ago I did try glmmADMB, but it did not yield better results.

Cheers, ZR

Comment: I know this is not what you asked but you are using a quadratic term in your pc variables without also including them as linear. This constrains your model and is not normally recommended. Is it what you intended?

Comment: @mdewey the rationale behind this, is that the relationship between weather effects and sampling success follows an optimum: the probability and extent of sampling success is highest in a given range (in this case, zero and its vicinity) of the predictor. When the predictor's value is further away from this optimum, the sampling success will be lower, corresponging to a suboptimum. I use the quadratic term, because (1) predictors are rescaled and recentered at zero, and (2) this gives a better approximation to a linear connection.

Cheers, ZR

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that point. It is quite rare to have a known minimum/maximum which is what made me raise it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is difficult to assess the fit of the Poisson (or any other integer-valued GLM for that matter) with Pearson or deviance residuals, because also a perfectly fitting Poisson GLMM will exhibit inhomogeneous deviance residuals.

This is especially so if you do GLMMs with observation-level REs, because the dispersion created by OL-REs is not considered by the Pearson residuals.

To demonstrate the issue, the following code creates overdispersed Poisson data, that is then fitted with a perfect model. The Pearson residuals look very much like your plot - hence, it may be that there is no problem at all.

This problem is solved by the [DHARMa R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html), which simulates from the fitted model to transform the residuals of any GL(M)M into a standardized space. Once this is done, you can visually assess / test residual problems, such as deviations from the distribution, residual dependency on a predictor, heteroskedasticity or autocorrelation in the normal way. See the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) for worked-through examples. You can see in the lower plot that the same model now looks fine, as it should.

If you still see heteroscedasticity after plotting with DHARMa, you will have to model dispersion as a function of something, which is not a big problem, but would likely require you to move to JAGs or another Bayesian software.

```
library(DHARMa)
library(lme4)

testData = createData(sampleSize = 200, overdispersion = 1, randomEffectVariance = 1, family = poisson())

fittedModel <- glmer(observedResponse ~ Environment1 + (1|group) + (1|ID), family = "poisson", data = testData, control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000) ))

# standard Pearson residuals
plot(fittedModel, resid(., type = "pearson") ~ fitted(.) , abline = 0)

# DHARMa residuals
plot(simulateResiduals(fittedModel))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear @FlorianHartig! Thank You for Your insights, I tried plotting with DHARMa. Based on the plot there is still something up, causeing the lower quantile to be shaped like a reciprocal curve, rather than a straight line. You have mentioned that in this case, a solution might be to model dispersion as a function of something - could You help in exactly how can i assess such a function?

Cheers, ZR

Comment: Can you send me or post the plot? Some minor variability is expected when your N is small

Comment: Dear @FlorianHartig the question was edited, now showing the DHARMa plots as well!

Comment: @Z.Radai - what I see in the plots is that your residuals are systematically too high for low model predictions. This looks more like a problem of model structure (missing predictors?) than a distribution problem - I would try plotting the residuals against possible and potentially missing predictors.

Comment: The ugly residuals might be the result of the unusual data (see the Fig in the update). Problem is, that for each month there is only a handful unique values in the weather-variables. That's because for a given area at a given time (year-month), I only have one value, while multiple response-values might occur in the same area and time; consequently, albeit in the dataset N > 500, only ca. 35 unique values are there for each weather variable. Not sure how can I resolve this issue, or even if the GLMM approach could work. Thoughts?

Comment: @Z.Radai the figure tells me very little - this is a multivariate setting, so this response might be perfectly explained by the other predictors. Plot residuals against predictors to check what's going on!

Comment: Dear @FlorianHartig I added a plot (as update II.) showing the relationship between predictors and residuals.

Comment: Well, ok, something seems to be going on towards smaller values of the PCA variables - I just noted that you only seem to include quadratic effects of the PCA - does that make any sense? Where are the linear predictors?

Comment: @FlorianHartig see Z's response to my comment under the original question.

Comment: @mdewey ah, ok, thanks! Z.Radai, the fact remains that it looks like you have a systematic misfit for small values, so you may want to reconsider your choice of predictors.

Comment: Dear @FlorianHartig In Your answer You have mentioned a possibility to 'model dispersion as a function of something' - could You explain this option?

Comment: I would not be concerned about heteroskedasticity, in your case it's moderate and the effect on the inference should be mild  - the only issue I see is the systematic underprediction for small values, which will not be solved by modeling the variance. But if you must know see here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247183/interpret-residual-vs-fitted-values-for-negative-binomial-glm/248176?noredirect=1#comment475988_248176